# SQL Server 2005 transaction

Tags: sql-server-2005

This may be very basic question. If we open a sql transaction with "Begin Transaction", is commit transaction or rollback is mandatory...?

I have a scenario where i need to exit the SP when a row exists in if statement fails. This if statement is currently inside the transaction scope..

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Bala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we open a sql transaction with "Begin Transaction", is commit transaction or rollback is mandatory...?

It's *not* mandatory, the transaction will stay open until an error or the connection is closed. But you don't want to do this, you may be blocking other users for a very long time.

You *should* `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` *at the earliest opportunity*.